# How to make a nodejs application work correctly on cPanel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cpanel

I am calling on you because I am trying in vain to make my nodejs application work with cPanel. This is the back api of my website coded with react. When I test my routes strangely I have to put different urls each time but without changing my code: sometimes the api only works if I put http, sometimes only with https or sometimes by putting doubles or even triples slach after the url from the api. It's very strange. I don't see where this problem could come from. So sometimes the information from my database is displayed and sometimes I get the error message 404: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**

And even when the api works I have this error on my frontend: **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://book2lifeapi.book2life.fr/api/v1/lastFreeBooks/categorie/1' from origin 'https://www. book2life.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

To correct this error I added cors on my application startup file:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

But that doesn't solve the problem because I have this new error displayed: **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://book2lifeapi.book2life.fr/api/v1/books/last' from origin 'https://www.book2life.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.  **

So I tried to add:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

But I got a 500 error when putting this code

Here are a few lines of code:

- code to call my API in my frontend:

```
export const config = {
    api_url: "https://book2lifeapi.book2life.fr",
    pict_url: "https://book2lifeapi.book2life.fr/images/"
};
```

- in my application startup file:

```
// connection to my database 
mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    database: database,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    port: port
}).then((db) => {
    console.log('connecté bdd');
    setInterval(async function () {
        let res = await db.query('SELECT 1');
    }, 10000);
    
    app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
        res.json({msg: 'Welcome to your book2life api !', status: 200})
    })

    //call of the roads
    userRoutes(app, db)
    adminRoutes(app, db)
    bookRoutes(app, db)
    adminAuthRoutes(app, db)
    userAuthRoutes(app, db)
    
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('listening port: '+PORT);
})
```

Can anyone tell me why my API works 1 out of 2 times? Why do I get cors errors even when it works? How to resolve this CORS problem when working on Cpanel because I cannot add app.use(cors()) and the header.

I'm really lost. This is the first time I'm trying to put a react and nodejs site online. Locally, everything works perfectly.